# Simplest linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list, memory-optimization

My context was basically to get my linked list implementation in C++ reviewed, since I wrote it from scratch and wanted to make it as simple as possible and learn from suggestions I get. I am trying to learn to create modular/re-usable, efficient (wrt time complexity), and yet simple code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *tail = NULL;
struct node *prev = NULL;

void print_list()
{
    struct node *foo = head;

    while (foo != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << foo->val << std::endl;
        foo = foo->next;
    }
}

void add_to_list(int value, bool add_to_end)
{
    struct node *foo = new (struct node);
    foo->val = value;
    foo->next = NULL;

    // If its a new list, then this is the first node, so tail and head both are the same !
    if(NULL == head)
        head = tail = foo;
    else if (add_to_end == true)
    {
        // Add to end of list
        tail->next = foo; 
        tail = foo; // After this statement, tail->next should obviously be NULL
    }
    else
    {
        // Add to beginning of list
        foo->next = head;
        head = foo;
    }
}

struct node * search_list(int value)
{
    struct node *foo = head;

    while(foo != NULL)
    {
        if(foo->val == value)
            return foo;
        else
        {
            prev = foo;
            foo = foo->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int delete_list(int value)
{
    struct node *foo = search_list(value);

    // Check if node exists
    if (foo == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (foo->val == head->val)
    {
        head = head->next;

        foo->next = NULL;
        delete(foo);
        foo = NULL;
    }
    else if (foo->val == tail->val)
    {
        //tail->next = prev->next;
        tail = prev;
        prev->next = foo->next;

        foo->next = NULL;
        delete(foo);
        foo = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = foo->next;

        foo->next = NULL;
        delete(foo);
        foo = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Testing add_to_list
    add_to_list(17, true);
    add_to_list(23, true);
    add_to_list(13, true);
    add_to_list(7, false);
    add_to_list(21, true);

    add_to_list(171, false);
    add_to_list(231, true);
    add_to_list(131, true);
    add_to_list(71, true);
    add_to_list(211, true);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Testing print_list
    std::cout << "\nPrinting the entire list...\n";
    print_list();
    std::cout << "Done printing the entire list !\n";
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------




    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Testing search_list
    int num = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter integer to search:\n";
    std::cin >> num;

    if (search_list(num) != NULL)
        std::cout << "Found in list ! :)\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not Found in list ! :(\n";
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------



    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Testing delete_list
    std::cout << "Enter integer to delete:\n";
    std::cin >> num;

    if (delete_list(num) != -1)
        std::cout << "Deleted node value " << num << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Not Found in list ! :(\n";

    std::cout << "\nPrinting the entire list...\n";
    print_list();
    std::cout << "Done printing the entire list !\n";
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Testing status of head, tail and prev nodes
    if (head == NULL)
        std::cout << "\nHead node is NULL !\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\nHead node value = " << head->val;

    if (tail == NULL)
        std::cout << "\ntail node is NULL !\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\ntail node value = " << tail->val;

    if (prev == NULL)
        std::cout << "\nprevious node value = NULL !\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\nprevious node value = " << prev->val;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Delete the entire list (releasing the memory used ofcourse !)
    std::cout << "\n|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\nDELETING ENTIRE LIST...\n||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n";
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        delete_list(head->val);
        std::cout << "\nPrinting the entire list...\n";
        print_list();
        std::cout << "Done printing the entire list !\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. I am sure you will get many great answers here. However, you may want to provide some context as to what your code is trying to achieve, and what you are hoping to learn from other programmers. See the Asking Questions section of the Help Center.

Comment: Do you want to mark this as `C` and remove the `C++` tag. This uses no C++ features (apart from std::cin/cout). This style is commonly referred to as `C with classes`.

Comment: @LokiAstari If this code compiles as [tag:c++], but won't compile as [tag:c], then it would absolutely not be appropriate to tag it as [tag:c]. "You're failing to use C++ idiomatically" would be a fine answer.

Comment: @ Joseph Farah - Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is my first time at codereview.stackexchange.com. My context was basically to get my linked list implementation in C++ reviewed, since I wrote it from scratch and wanted to make it as simple as possible and learn from suggestions I get. I am trying to learn to create modular/re-usable, efficient (wrt time complexity), and yet simple code.

Comment: @ Loki Astari  and @ 200_success - Thanks for your comments. This code is compiled using g++ and does not compile with a C compiler and hence is technically C++ only. However, I do get your point that I did not leverage on a lot of C++ features, probably except for very few, such as "new" & "delete", std::cout/cin, etc.

Comment: @ZeZNiQ: I've included your comment into the question text to make it more than just a blob of code.

Answer (score 5):

I can see a few things about this that seem open to improvement.

#### Avoid Globals

It's generally best to avoid globals, especially mutable ones. Instead of the global `head`, `tail` and `prev` pointers, it's probably better to create a `linked_list` class, and create an instance of that class that we'll manipulate, instead of writing our code assuming that there can only be one linked list in the program.

```
struct node { /* ... */ };

class linked_list { 
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    // ...
```

`prev` seems to only be used by one function, so I think it should probably be local to that function, not a member of the class proper (well, they way you're using it now, it's shared between `search` and `delete`, but given a choice I'd eliminate that as well--it strikes me as quite fragile).

#### Writing Output

Next we get to `print_list`. In C++ writing an object to a stream is traditionally done with `stream << object;` This is done by overloading `operator<<` for that type of object, something like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, linked_list const &ll) // ...
```

...and that has to walk through the linked list, printing the nodes, just like `print_list` did.

It's also worth considering adding an overload of `operator<<` to `struct node`, so that the linked_list doesn't need to know about what's in a node--it just prints nodes, and leaves it to `node` to know how to print itself.

#### List Manipulation

Then we get to the functions that manipulate the linked list. These probably make sense as members of the `linked_list` class. As member functions, they'll get access to the `head` and `tail` members of the class. So, `add_to_list` can become just `list::add` (and likewise, `delete_list` becomes `list::remove` (we don't want to name it just `delete`, since that has a special meaning in C++).

#### Adding

Looking specifically at `add_to_list`, it has a Boolean parameter. At least in my view, this is pretty much a no no--it's not at all apparent what `add_to_list(1, false)` vs. `add_to_list(1, true)` really means. I'd rather define an enumeration like: `enum { atHead, atTail };`, so these look like: `some_list.add(1, atHead);` or `some_list.add(3, atTail);`. At least to me, that makes the code considerably easier to understand. Another possibility would be to just have two separate functions: `add_head` and `add_tail`.

#### Destroying a list

I'd probably also add a destructor to the class, which would delete all the nodes in the list, about like the code you already have in `main` to delete all the nodes in the list.

#### Initialize in the ctor

I'd probably define a constructor for `node` that requires a value to be passed in for `val`, and initializes its `next` pointer as well:

```
node(int val, node *next = nullptr) : val(val), next(next) { }
```

#### Consider using a sentinel

One way you can make most linked list code a *lot* cleaner is to have a sentinel node. If there's a value you don't need for other purposes, you can allocate a node containing that value when you create the list. This simplifies quite a bit of other code--it eliminates the special case for adding the first node to the list, and eliminates the case where you ever delete the last element from the list (which leads to a much simpler way to do deletion).

Incorporating these, we could end up with code something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;

    node(int val, node *next = nullptr) : val(val), next(next) { }
};

class linked_list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    static const int sentinel = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
public:
    void add_head(int);
    void add_tail(int);

    bool remove(int);
    node *search(int);

    linked_list() { head = tail = new node(sentinel); }

    ~linked_list();

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, linked_list const &);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, linked_list const &ll) {
    node *foo = ll.head;

    while (foo->val != linked_list::sentinel) {
        std::cout << foo->val << "\n";
        foo = foo->next;
    }
    return os;
}

void linked_list::add_head(int value) {
    head = new node(value, head);
}

void linked_list::add_tail(int value) {
    tail->next = new node(value, tail);
    tail = tail->next;
}

node * linked_list::search(int value) {
    for (node *foo = head; foo->val != sentinel; foo = foo->next)
        if (foo->val == value)
            return foo;
    return nullptr;
}

bool linked_list::remove(int value) {
    node *foo = search(value);

    if (foo == nullptr)
        return false;

    node *temp = foo->next;
    foo->val = temp->val;
    foo->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
    return true;
}

linked_list::~linked_list() {
    node *pos = head;
    while (pos != nullptr) {
        node *temp = pos;
        pos = pos->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

#### Make it Generic

I haven't incorporated it in the code above, but one final addition would be to make the code generic, so it can store essentially any type of object, not just an `int`. Doing this thoroughly requires a fair amount of extra explanation, and leads to a fairly fundamental shift in how the code is written, so I'll leave it alone (at least for now).

#### Finally, don't use a linked list

Testing shows, over and over again, the linked lists are useful much less often than most people assume they will be. In theory, they allow constant-complexity insertion and deletion at any point in the collection--but neither your code nor mine actually supports that. Instead, insertion is only allowed at the head or tail, and deletion takes linear complexity. Defining a linked list so you can make use of its constant-complexity capabilities is non-trivial, and putting that to use so you gain a real advantage is harder still.

In short, linked lists add complexity but give little in return for it much more often than not.

Comment: This is the first time I used codereview.stackexchange.com, and I gotta admit it, I'm impressed ! Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I did try running your code using g++, however, there are a number of errors. By the first look of it, it seems its few compiler arguments I will need to add and few more things I need to figure out in order to get it running. Once I get it running, I will get back to you on my observations and will try to incorporate the additional suggestions that you mentioned, such as making it generic, etc. Once again, thanks a lot for helping me become a better programmer.

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - Following are the errors of your code: (I tried rectifying a few, such as the numeric one by adding the limits header, the compiler argument of -std=c++0x for nullptr, etc.)
prac.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const linked_list&)’:
prac.cpp:33:24: error: ‘sentinel’ was not declared in this scope
     while (foo->val != sentinel)
                        ^

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - ..continued..prac.cpp: At global scope:
prac.cpp:49:8: error: ‘list’ has not been declared
 node * list::search(int value) {
        ^
prac.cpp: In function ‘node* search(int)’:
prac.cpp:50:22: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
     for (node *foo = head; node->val != sentinel; node = node->next)
                      ^

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - ..continued..prac.cpp:50:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘->’ token
     for (node *foo = head; node->val != sentinel; node = node->next)
                                ^
prac.cpp:50:41: error: ‘sentinel’ was not declared in this scope
     for (node *foo = head; node->val != sentinel; node = node->next)
                                         ^
prac.cpp:50:56: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
     for (node *foo = head; node->val != sentinel; node = node->next)
                                                        ^

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - ..continued.. prac.cpp:50:62: error: expected primary-expression before ‘->’ token
     for (node *foo = head; node->val != sentinel; node = node->next)
                                                              ^
prac.cpp: In function ‘bool remove(int)’:
prac.cpp:62:5: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope
     temp = foo->next;
     ^
prac.cpp:65:12: error: type ‘<type error>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
     delete temp;
            ^

Comment: @ZeZNiQ: I apologize--I accidentally posted the code as I originally typed it in, before running it through the compiler to  catch my typos and such. I believe it's better now...

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - Works like a charm ! Beautiful piece of code ! Thanks a lot for your review Jerry. I'll need to comprehend what you did to the code to make it work so well, by incorporating each part of your suggestion one by one into my posted code. I hope my final code ends up being the same as yours, if not better. And then, I will try my best to incorporate your suggestions in "Make it Generic" and "Finally, don't use a linked list" parts of your comment. Thanks again !

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - Could you pelase explain why you defined the struct node outside the class? Why not define the struct inside the class linked_list? Any advantages and disadvantages of either way?

Comment: @ZeZNiQ: No particular reason--I've done it both ways, and never seen a substantial difference. Defining `node` inside of `linked_list` reduces namespace clutter, but it does make the code at hand marginally less readable.

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin -Thanks Jerry ! One of ur suggestions were to try not to use globals. Do you think defining struct node outside of class is going against that suggestion?

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - Is it advisable to use stl or any such standard libraries for data structure implementations or is it advisable to implement ur own? For example, wud u want to implement your own linked list or use the one in stl through #include <list> or any such standard libraries?

Comment: @ZeZNiQ: Especially in production code, I'd *definitely* use the code from the standard library unless I had a specific reason I *had* to write my own.

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin - Thanks Jerry. Does C++, or for that matter any programming language, have more than 1 standard library? For example, in C++ would you recommend I make use of the standard template library (STL) for linked list or any data structure or for everything the STL library has to offer?